# A system where/in which

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

I was wondering after using the word *system* which word is more appropriate to use in order to explain and give more details about it: "where" or "in which"?

I can observe that both words are used but should it be chosen according to the context or their usage overlaps and does not change meaning much if we prefer one to another.

Following examples were excerpted from Google search results:

> We develop a mathematical analysis for the steady state performance of
>   a system **where** voice calls and data packets are transmitted over the
>   same ..
>
> How can we create a political system **where** elected representatives
>   care much less about winning the next election and instead ...
>
> A parliamentary republic is a system **in which** a prime minister is the
>   active head of the executive branch of government and also leader of
>   the ...
>
> A multi-party system is a system 
>   **in which** multiple political parties
>   across the political spectrum run for national election, and all have
>   the capacity to gain control of government offices, separately or in
>   coalition.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen tricky questions about this on English tests.  It depends on the degree of formality.

In highly formal English (including English tests unless otherwise specified), "where" should only be used for a physical location.  Since "in the system" isn't a physical location, you have to use "in which".

In general use, including business and technology, "where" and "in which" are used interchangeably.

In casual use, "in which" (or any preposition + 'which') sounds stilted and awkward and is normally avoided, so you have to use "where".

Answer (score 1):

They will be understood if used interchageably, but *in which* speaks to the structure, and *where* speaks to the ideas.

> Democracy is a system **where** each person has a vote **in which** they can express their opinion.

Comment: Are you saying that "Democracy is a system in which each person has a vote" is incorrect? If so why? If not, why did you give that example?